# GWT UIBinder method return type void?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

Bellow is some Java code from [Google's `UIBinder` tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder#Overview). Together with a separate HTML page this code displays the text "Hello, World".

```
public class HelloWorld {
    interface MyUiBinder extends UiBinder<DivElement, HelloWorld> {}
    private static MyUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyUiBinder.class);

    @UiField SpanElement nameSpan;

    public HelloWorld() {
        setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    public void setName(String name) { 
        nameSpan.setInnerText(name); 
    }

    /**
    * Method in question
    */
    public void Element getElement() { 
        return nameSpan; 
    }
}
```

The getElement() method has a void return type but returns an `Element` called `nameSpan`. How is this possible given that it has a `void` return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is simply, that the example in the documentation is "a little bit" broken.

The implementation of `setElement()` and `getElement()` would be unnecessary anyway, if the example simply extended UIObject like

```java
public class HelloWorld extends UIObject {

  private static HelloWorldUiBinder uiBinder = 
        GWT.create(HelloWorldUiBinder.class);

  interface HelloWorldUiBinder extends UiBinder<Element, HelloWorld> {
  }

  @UiField
  SpanElement nameSpan;

  public HelloWorld() {
    setElement(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  public void setName(String name) { 
    nameSpan.setInnerText(name); 
  }

}
```

---

By the way, here's a standalone variation of the UiBinder "hello world" example (which might be easier to understand as a first UiBinder example):

```java
public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {

  interface HelloWorldUiBinder extends UiBinder<Element, HelloWorld> {
  }

  @UiField SpanElement nameSpan;

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    final HelloWorldUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(HelloWorldUiBinder.class);
    final Element element = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);
    nameSpan.setInnerText("world");
    Document.get().getBody().appendChild(element);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this definitely looks like a much better way of doing things! Not sure why the official example uses such an odd approach, doesn't exactly look like best practice to me. I'll do some research on using UIObjects.

Comment: Have a look at the last paragraph in the section: the purpose of the example is to demonstrate that you don't _have_ to extend `UIObject` or `Widget` or whatever; they also say it's not a _real_ example, but "it shows us the bare nuts and bolts". FYI, starting with GWT 2.1, I've started to replace `extends Composite` with `implements IsWidget`.